# Why does PostgreSQL mangle my hex input in a LIKE query?

Tags: postgresql, bytea

On some `LIKE` queries on a `bytea` column, PostgreSQL is mangling my input byte sequence. Why could this be happening?

```
Expected query plan:    b >= '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfc5cdc0bd39c29'::bytea
From actual query plan: b >= '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfcdc0bd39c29'::bytea
```

Notice the difference in the byte sequences (spaces show missing byte):

```
Expected: \x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfc5cdc0bd39c29
Actual:   \x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfc  dc0bd39c29
```

Table:

```
=> \d tbl
                 table "tbl"
 Column |   Type    | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+-----------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | int       |           |          |
 b      | bytea     |           |          |
```

Query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE b LIKE '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfc5cdc0bd39c29'::bytea||'%'
```

Query planner:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE b LIKE '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfc5cdc0bd39c29'::bytea||'%';
                                           QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using idx on tbl (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=670 width=172) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((b >= '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfcdc0bd39c29'::bytea) AND (b < '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfcdc0bd39c2a'::bytea))
   Filter: (b ~~ '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfc5cdc0bd39c2925'::bytea)
 Planning Time: 0.090 ms
 Execution Time: 0.033 ms
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be using operators that expect string input on `bytea` data, because it'll be implicitly converted to a string. `0x5c` is a backslash symbol, so it gets processed as it would in a string (e.g. taken as an escape character).

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out! PostgreSQL is interpreting the `\x5c` as a backslash, which is an escape sequence in `LIKE` expressions. To fix the query, I just need to repeat the `5c` to correctly escape the backslash:

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE b LIKE '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfc5c5cdc0bd39c29'::bytea||'%';
                                           QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using idx on tbl (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=670 width=172) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((b >= '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfc5cdc0bd39c29'::bytea) AND (b < '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfcdc0bd39c2a'::bytea))
   Filter: (b ~~ '\x4cbf996e2c527620d067571c6f650643edfc5cdc0bd39c2925'::bytea)
 Planning Time: 0.090 ms
 Execution Time: 0.033 ms
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Why are you using `bytea` if you want to treat the values as  strings? `text` would be the better data type in that case.